# Ridiculously high R2 score for linear regression model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am running a linear regression model on a dataset which has 88 columns. Most of them are binary - containing only 1 or 0. The rest have numeric values of the datatype float64. When I run a linear regression model on this, I get ridiculously high negative r2_scores.
I am not able to understand why this must be so. The only difference that I can see is if i change the datatype of the float columns to int, the r2 score falls by an order of magnitude (still high).
Has any of you come across a similar problem?

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
 model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True)
 model.fit(X_train,y_train)
 pred_Y=model.predict(X_test)
 r2=r2_score(y_test,pred_Y)
 print(r2)
```

r2=-14440.99304389795

Comment: There is no way anyone can figure out what the issue is without taking a look at your data and the rest of your code. Please make sure that the issue is reproducible.

Comment: Thank you MZ, I think that is the problem indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by MZ is the correct explanation for the problem. However, playing around with the random state a couple of times solved the issue for me! Thanks!